# pip install django-allauth- Error: No module named 'allauth.socialaccountallauth' python django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-allauth

I'm trying to add social authentication to my login page .

for that i have installed `pip install django-allauth` to my project.
I have added required apps it to the `INSTALLED_APP`, added `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`, `SITE_ID` and the path to the project urls.py

you can check for the tutorial here
https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

the thing is when i try to migrate it raises the following error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth.socialaccountallauth'`

how can I solve it. If anyone can hepl me with it.

one thing that i feel could be the problem is that i already have an app named `accounts_app` in my project which have the path
`path('accounts/', include('accounts_app.urls')),`
and the socialauth path is `path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),`

if this could be the problem then how can i solve it without changing my accounts_app.

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for camroid_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path
from django.contrib.messages import constants as messages
from decouple import config

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
# SECRET_KEY = 'f@(w5t$z*7zyia!@i#(pksruu$nucw#u-f2qd#%9^g1^(*^lsx'

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'camroid_app.apps.CamroidAppConfig',
    'accounts_app.apps.AccountsAppConfig',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount'
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',

]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'camroid_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'camroid_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('HOST'),
    }
}


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

]


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


#email verification

EMAIL_BACKEND = config('EMAIL_BACKEND')
EMAIL_HOST = config('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = config('EMAIL_USE_TLS', cast=bool)
EMAIL_PORT = config('EMAIL_PORT', cast=int)
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')


MESSAGE_TAGS = {
    messages.ERROR: 'danger',
    50: 'critical',
}
```

**trace**

```
 C:\Users\SandeepNegi\Desktop\CAMROID\camroid_project>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\SandeepNegi\.virtualenvs\CAMROID-nt7jYvBL\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\SandeepNegi\.virtualenvs\CAMROID-nt7jYvBL\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\SandeepNegi\.virtualenvs\CAMROID-nt7jYvBL\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\SandeepNegi\.virtualenvs\CAMROID-nt7jYvBL\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\SandeepNegi\.virtualenvs\CAMROID-nt7jYvBL\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "c:\users\sandeepnegi\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth.socialaccountallauth'
```

Comment: The urls are a problem but not related to the error above. Post your settings.py and the whole error message with full traceback.

Comment: You might not have added all the packages in the settings.py and remember "THE ORDER MATTERS"

Comment: ok there was a missing comma in installed_app @melvyn answered me bellow. but thanx for your help

Comment: I stuck into a problem. as i mentioned i had an accounts_app with the path('accounts/') and my socialauth is also having path ('accounts/') .detail i have mentioned in ques. Now when i login . it overwrite my accounts_app url . but i want to use my own created template which will have the link of google sign in . how can i do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error explains it all:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth.socialaccountallauth'
                                                           ^^^^^^^
```

That last part shouldn't be there. See the documentation you linked. It's likely you forgot a comma:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'allauth.socialaccount' # missing comma
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.gitlab'
)
```

Will produce that error, because the two strings will be joined.

Comment: thanx this help.